# Pass ArrayList<Double> from one activity to another activity on android

Tags: android

I've stored `ArrayList<Double>` on my bean class,

I've the bean class on my main activity,

How to pass the `ArrayList<Double>` ,from my main activity to another activity.?

My array list is double.  how to pass double arraylist ?

Comment: go2OtherActivity.putParcelableArrayListExtra("doubleList",yourCustomeDoubleList); yourCustomeDoubleList must Parcelable interface

Comment: Hi @subodh  can u explain briefly. My array list is double.

Comment: Look at my updated answer. I updated with code..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This one helps you...

```
public Intent putParcelableArrayListExtra (String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)
```

For more info look at [putParcelableArrayListExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29)

**EDIT:**

If you have a `double[]` then you can use

`void putDoubleArray(String key, double[] value)` of [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) class..

Inserts a double array value into the mapping of this Bundle, replacing any existing value for the given key.
And pass this bundle to Intent to Other Activity.

**Update:2**

**FirstActivity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
ArrayList<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<Double>();
listDouble.add(1111.00000);
listDouble.add(13331.00000);
intent.putExtra("arraylist", listDouble);
startActivity(intent);
```

**OtherActivity:** (Retrieve Double ArrayList)

```
ArrayList<Double> listDouble = (ArrayList<Double>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
System.out.println("...serialized data.." + listDouble);
```

Comment: Hi @user370305 hi. my arraylist is double.  could u explain briefly. how to pass double arraylist ?

Comment: Hi @user370305 i need another help, can we pass the "bean" class from main activity to another activity?

Comment: hi @user370305 i arise the question here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664210/how-to-pass-bean-class-one-activity-to-another-activity-on-android

Comment: hi @user370305 do u know the solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883879/route-half-way-point-on-android-code

Answer (score 1):

Refer below method to pass data from one activity to other

**Eg 1**

```
putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value)
putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)
putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value)
putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<CharSequence> value)
```

Then you can read from you next activity by replacing put with get with key string as argument,eg

```
myIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("array");
```

**Eg 2**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,name.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value);
//b.putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value);
//b.putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value);
i.putExtra(String name,b);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider passing parameters to an other activity though Intent Extras :

```
Intent.putExtra()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will demonstrate that how to pass a double array object  to other activity  through inent

```
String [] my_dblArray=new Sting[no];
   //put some value in the array and then pass through intent
Intent intnt=new Intent(this,YourReqActivity.class);            
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putDoubleArray("doubleVal",my_dblArray);  
intnt.putExtra(bundle);
startActivity(intnt);
```

// At Receiver side put this line of code.

```
 String [] dblval=Bndl.getDoubleArray("doubleVal");
```