# How to pass bean class one activity to another activity on android

Tags: android

Hi  this is my listview onClicklister.

when i click the list item , I pass the the arraylist which is getting from bean class one activity to another activity like below.,

But i want to know can we pass the bean class to next activity?

```
listViewRoutes.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
          long arg3) {
        RouteBean bean = routeList.get(arg2);
        ArrayList<Double> fromLatitude = bean.getFromLatitude();
        ArrayList<Double> fromLongitude= bean.getFromLongitude();
        ArrayList<Double> toLatitude = bean.getToLatitude();
        ArrayList<Double> toLongitude= bean.getToLongitude();
        Intent intent =new Intent("MapActivityView");
        intent.putExtra("fromLon", fromLongitude);
        intent.putExtra("fromLat", fromLatitude);
        intent.putExtra("toLat", toLatitude);
        intent.putExtra("toLon", toLongitude);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
```

if i pass the "Route Bean", i get the values on next activity.

Is it possible to pass the bean class ?

Comment: Look [here][1]. There are many ways to do that.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679574/app-design-pass-date-through-intents-or-use-singletons/11679728#11679728

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass your object using `Parcelable` class..

something like,

```
public class RouteBean implements Parcelable {

}
```

Once you have your objects implement `Parcelable` it's just a matter of putting them into your Intents with `putExtra()`:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("object", Parcelable_Object);
```

Then you can pull them back out with `getParcelableExtra()`:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
RouteBean bean = (RouteBean) i.getParcelableExtra("object");
```

For more info look at this SO question [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: Hi @user370305, i need another one help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682164/find-center-geopoint-between-start-geo-point-and-end-geo-point-on-android

Comment: hi @user370305, i need another one help , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623302/get-meta-data-of-image-android/12623648#12623648

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible. You have to send the Object of your class like this,

```
   intent.putExtra("RouteBean", bean);
```

And retrieve it like this in your next activity,

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("RouteBean");
```

But your class has to implement `Serializable` Interface.

Or you can use Parcelable Interface,

Here is a Example,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6923794/603744

For the first method, your class should be like this,

```
public class RouteBean implements Serializable 
{

}
```

And for the next one,

```
public class RouteBean implements Parcelable 
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your RouteBean class implements `Parcelable` interface. Then you can pass your custom class objects as bundle in intent to other activity.

You can then use-

class RouteBean implements Parceable
Then while calling intent.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
RouteBean yourObj = new RouteBean();
bundle.putParcelable("bundlename", yourObj);
```

And in next Activity you can use

```
RouteBean yourObj bundle.getParcelable("bundlename");
```

More info on Parceable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by `in1.putExtra("beanObject", bean)`.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {

            bean = (ActivitiesBean) adapter.getItem(position); //ActivitiesBean is the name of the bean class

            Intent in1 = new Intent(firstclass.this, secondclass.class);
            in1.putExtra("beanObject", bean);
            startActivity(in1);
        }

    });
```

and use this for the secondclass.java

```
ActivitiesBean bean =  (ActivitiesBean) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("beanObject");
txt_title.setText(bean.getTitle());  //txt_title is the object of the textview
```