# App design: Pass date through Intents or use Singletons?

Tags: android, singleton

I'm creating an app where I need to pass relatively complex classes between several `Activity`s and `Service`s. Lets say something like this:

```
public class A implements Serializable{

    int myInt;
    String myString;
    B myB;
}

public class B implements Serializable{
    ArrayList<String> myStrings;
}
```

Now this can be done by `Intent.putExtra(String, Serializable)`, but I could also create a singleton class holding the `A` instance. Using a singleton provides easy access to my instance of `A`, but it seems a bit 'hacky' to me.

What are the up and down sides of using both methods? Are there any strict reasons why I shouldn't use one of the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this [share data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities).

You could use intents, Singletons class, A public static field/method, A HashMap of WeakReferences to Objects, Application Preferences, Files, contentProviders, SQLite DB.

Look here [Android FAQ](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3)