# Find center geopoint between  start geo point and end geo point on android

Tags: android

I have start latitude, longitude and end latitude,longitude.

I find Geo Point using latitude and longitude.

After that i draw line between the two Geo points.

My question is how to find the center of the Geopoint?

I display "OverlayItem" on start and end position. But unable to find the center of the Geopoint.

How to find center point?

i use below code for display overlayItem on start and end position.

```
        drawable            = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.annot_start);
        point               = new GeoPoint((int)(startLatitude*1E6), (int)(startLongitude*1E6));
        overlayItem         = new OverlayItem(point, startAddress, "Welcome");
        itemizedOverlay[n]= new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
        itemizedOverlay[n].addOverlay(overlayItem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay[n]);

        drawable            = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.annot_end);
        point               = new GeoPoint((int)(endLatitude*1E6), (int)(endLongitude*1E6));
        overlayItem         = new OverlayItem(point, endAddress, "Welcome");
        itemizedOverlay[n+1]= new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
        itemizedOverlay[n+1].addOverlay(overlayItem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay[n+1]);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Haversine formula` snippet and checked with this [page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

```
public static void midPoint(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2){

double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

//convert to radians
lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
lon1 = Math.toRadians(lon1);

double Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
double By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
double lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By));
double lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);

//print out in degrees
System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(lat3) + " " + Math.toDegrees(lon3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the midpoint by taking the average of the latitudes of the two points and the average of the longitudes.

If you need it a bit more precisely, you can use [the Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and some algebra to derive the midpoint.

Comment: Hi @Trott, could u pls explain briefly.

Answer (score 0):

The checked solution does not work for me.

Anyway, i have found an easiest solution :

```
   private GeoPoint midPoint(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2){
        //create origin geopoint from parameters
        GeoPoint origin = new GeoPoint(lat1,lon1);
        //create destination geopoints from parameters
        GeoPoint destination = new GeoPoint(lat2,lon2);
        //calculate and return center
        return GeoPoint.fromCenterBetween(origin, destination);
    }
```

If you have origin and destination as GeoPoint, you can use directly "GeoPoint.fromCenterBetween" method.

Comment: where does GeoPoint come from? is that java or c#?