# How to find center point of two latitude longitude?

Tags: php

I have two latitude, longitude, now how i can find the center latitude,longitude of that two latitude longitude. 
 Can anybody help me?

Comment: Which projection are you using?

Comment: This is quite simple just add the both lat and divide by 2 and similar to longitude add both and divide by 2.

Comment: You can use search for example ;) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682164/find-center-geopoint-between-start-geo-point-and-end-geo-point-on-android)

Answer (score 3):

Define what is 'center' for you. Mostly, i use simple average. Better solution is to compute two vectors (from center of the earth), add them and normalize result. [Calculate the center point of multiple latitude/longitude coordinate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671183/calculate-the-center-point-of-multiple-latitude-longitude-coordinate-pairs)

Answer (score 2):

Also, be careful about longitudes. The midpoint between two points at 170° E and 170° W should be at 180° E *(or W)*, but you may end up with 0° E.

Download *Map Projections: A Working Manual*, by John P. Snyder, from the USGS. http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395. It's free.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your latitudes and longitudes to radians, then

```
$deltaLongitude = $endPointLongitude - $startPointlongitude;

$xModified = cos($endPointLatitude) * cos($deltaLongitude);
$yModified = cos($endPointLatitude) * sin($deltaLongitude);

$midpointLatitude = atan2(
    sin($startPointlatitude) + sin($endPointLatitude),
    sqrt((cos($startPointLatitude) + $xModified) * (cos($startPointLatitude) + $xModified) + 
         $yModified * $yModified
    )
);
$midpointLongitude = $startPointLongitude +
    atan2($yModified, 
        cos($startPointLatitude) + $xModified
    );
```

Comment: Clearly I'm wrong from the downvote: anybody care to explain so that __I__ can learn from the gurus as well

Comment: +1 for having a stab at it. I think (without trying to get a headache) it is down to Riemannian circle - Now the heady duty maths come into play.

Comment: Thanks, looks like more reading (and heavy math)

Comment: Here is a reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circles