# Calculate the co-ordinate between two decimal co-ordinate pairs, based on input distance

Tags: python, databricks

I have pairs of lat_lon values that form a linestring e.g. [16.36920394, 48.20342942], [35.93935074, 31.95158219]. For example, if the distance in km between those values is 843.905, how would I find the lat_lon value for the point that's exactly 300km between those values?

If I use my function below, I get the same output regardless of the distance I use. Is there something wrong with the calculation, or is my function formatted incorrectly?

```
# This function calculates the point between two decimal co-ordinate pairs, based on the distance (in km) travelled between them.

def find_point(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, distance_km):

    #convert from decimal degrees to radians 
    lat1_rad = math.radians(lat1)
    lat2_rad = math.radians(lat2)
    lon1_rad = math.radians(lon1)
    lon2_rad = math.radians(lon2)

    # find the distance between the two points in radians 
    d_rad = math.acos((math.sin(lat1_rad)*math.sin(lat2_rad) + 
    math.cos(lat1_rad)* math.cos(lat2_rad)*
    math.cos((lon2_rad - lon1_rad))))
    
    # calculate the distance between the two points in km
    distance = d_rad * 6371
    
    #calculate the bearing between the two points
    bearing = math.atan2(math.sin((lon2_rad-lon1_rad)), 
    math.cos(lat1_rad) * math.sin(lat2_rad) - 
    math.sin(lat1_rad) * math.cos(lat2_rad) * 
    math.cos((lon2_rad - lon1_rad)))
    
    #calculate the lat_lon of the intermediate point 
    lat_int = lat1_rad + distance/6371 * math.sin(d_rad)
    lon_int = lon1_rad + distance/6371 * math.cos(d_rad) * math.sin(bearing)
    
    # convert the lat_lon int values from radians to decimal degrees
    lat_int = math.degrees(lat_int)
    lon_int = math.degrees(lon_int)

    return lon_int, lat_int
```

Comment: Have you seen Mosaic (https://github.com/databrickslabs/mosaic/)? Not sure, but it may have necessary functionality

Comment: I know of Mosiac, but I've never really used it so I don't even know where I'd start with that. Honestly, I think the function I have should work and it's pretty basic, so I don't know where I'd start figuring something like that out. Thank you very much for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682164/find-center-geopoint-between-start-geo-point-and-end-geo-point-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic

point1 = (16.36920394, 48.20342942)
point2 = (35.93935074, 31.95158219)
distance_between_points = 843.905  # Distance in km

fraction = 300 / distance_between_points

lat1, lon1 = point1
lat2, lon2 = point2

intermediate_lat = lat1 + (lat2 - lat1) * fraction
intermediate_lon = lon1 + (lon2 - lon1) * fraction

lat_lon = intermediate_lat, intermediate_lon
print(lat_lon)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried the code, but I got an error that 'point' object has no attribute 'interpolate'. I've tried importing packages like Shapely but still get the same error. Is there a package missing by any chance?