# Get Meta Data of Image - Android

Tags: android, metadata, android-image

http://www.isco.com/webproductimages/appBnr/bnr1.jpg

I've used [a website](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?dummy=on&imgurl=http://www.isco.com/webproductimages/appBnr/bnr1.jpg) to see the metadata of a image. In this website, it shows all info of image. I want to know how to get the "Title" tag of above image in android.

I found here the similiar question for iOS only: [How to get image metadata in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478502/how-to-get-image-metadata-in-ios)

However I don't know how to get "Meta data" of image on android. `ExifInterface` only gives some informations. But I'm unable to get "Title" tag with it.

Can you provide any code snippet for get meta data in android for image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Download metadata extractor from the link given here ...... [click to download the library](http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/downloads/list)
choose the version 2.5.0.RC-3.zip

Extract the jar Folder

and import jar into libs folder in your poject and then execute the below code

```
        try {
            InputStream is = new URL("your image url").openStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(bis,true);


    for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
    for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
        System.out.println(tag);
    }
 }

            }
        catch (ImageProcessingException e){}
        catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: I've got a .jpg and it says `ImageProcessingException: File format is not supported`. I'm reading a .jpg image. Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me to get picture orientation from iOS device on my android. Thanks !

Comment: Works well with Kotlin. I just included implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.18.0' in my grade app build file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve meta data information about an image [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) is what you are looking for. Here is a quite good example of how this interface is used: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/12/read-exif-information-in-jpeg-file.html

But if you want to retrieve information of an online image I'm afraid it's not yet possible.

Comment: hi @korhanwzturk. thanks for reply. i've seen  exifinterface, but it did nt get basic information of image like title.

Comment: Exif interface has its own limitations as well. Like it returns null value for corrupted images.Better avoid it.

Comment: returning null for most of things only width and height is correct.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrieve metadata from image in Android project, then you can do that with the help of: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor

Implement this in your gradle using

```
implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.12.0'
```

Complete code is as follows

```
private static String getImageMetaData(Uri image1) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = FILE_CONTEXT.getContentResolver().openInputStream(image1);
        try {
            image1.getEncodedUserInfo();
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(inputStream);

            for (Directory directory1 : metadata.getDirectories()) {
                if (directory1.getName().equals("Exif IFD0")) {
                    for (Tag tag : directory1.getTags()) {
                        if (tag.getTagName().equals("Date/Time")) {
                            return tag.getDescription();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```