# How can I show a link posted in newsfeed? If it contains an image it also needs to be shown

Tags: android, feed

Suppose the link share value for google link from *api* is

```
<a target='_blank' href='https://www.google.co.in/' target='_blank'>
     https://www.google.co.in/
</a>

<h5>
    <a target='_blank' href='https://www.google.co.in/' target='_blank'>
        Google
    </a>
</h5>
<section class='detail-hldr'>
    <blockquote class='smal-video-pnl'>
        <figure class='smal-video-thumb'> 
            <img src='https://www.google.co.in/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png' class='max-width370' alt='Google'> 
        </figure>
    </blockquote>
</section>"
```

How can this be shown in the newsfeed?. Do we need to use a `textview` or a combination of `textview` and `imageview`? 

I have no idea, please help...
 expected output ..

[image]

Comment: how about WebView to show the share value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do like ***Facebook***. In Web, we do this by extracting the `meta-data` from link and then displaying it accordingly. Here is the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) to learn about **Meta Tag** and its component.

In Android, We can use [metadata-extractor](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/downloads/list). Download the latest version `.jar` and import it into your project `libs` folder.

And then use the following code to get meta-data :

```
try {
            InputStream is = new URL("your image url").openStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(bis,true);

      for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
       for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
         System.out.println(tag);
       }
      }
    }catch (ImageProcessingException e){}
     catch (IOException e) {}
```

Referenced from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623302/get-meta-data-of-image-android) StackOverflow Answer.