# How to get date of a selected photo from gallery in android application

Tags: android, date, image-gallery

I want to select a photo from the gallery and set it to a imageview. Up to now I did it.Now I want to get some details like name,date (details of the photo) of that photo.So how can I do this?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389225/android-how-to-get-a-files-creation-date

Comment: use this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623302/get-meta-data-of-image-android

Comment: Thak you so much saber.The link helped me