# How to send and receive an ArrayList from one activity to another activity in Android?

Tags: android

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("countiesof",
                (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) jsonDataList);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivty.class);

        intent.putExtra("mycountries", jsonDataList);

        startActivity(intent);
```

Now ,I want to pass arraylist from one to another activity.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another/21250450#21250450

Comment: what kind of objects you are storing in the jsonDataList ? are they parcelable ?

Comment: What and how exactly your arraylist is designed? Please show which arraylist you want to pass?

Comment: Array List with hash map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare you ArrayList as a static one like this,

```
public static ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

By doing this you can access your ArrayList from anywhere by

```
activity_name.array;
```

where activity_name is the activity or class in which you declare the static ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivty.class);

   putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value)

    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: `jsonDataList.toString()`? if `jsonDataList` was a list of object did this is a good way?

Comment: you can use this easily.

Comment: it's a very bad approach, you must use `Parcelable` or `Serializable` to send one list ( i prefer `Parcelable` because it is faster )

Comment: bad approach again, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340776/passing-a-list-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: where i use this? can you show me.

Answer (score 0):

Already i've asked passing data one activity to another. pls read this thread.

[How to pass bean class one activity to another activity on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664210/how-to-pass-bean-class-one-activity-to-another-activity-on-android)