# Route half way point on android code

Tags: android, google-maps

i've drawn line like this,

and i've found Mid point  using below code,

```
        public void midPoint(double lat1,double lon1,double lat2,double lon2){

        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

        lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        lon1 = Math.toRadians(lon1);

        double Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
        double By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
        finalLat= Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By)));
        finalLng= Math.toDegrees(lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx));
    }
```

Its successfully working..

[image]

But i'm unable to find the "R"- Route Half Way point.,  How to find the route half way point on android. i've searched on web, i found the https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-find-a-point-half-way-between-two-other-points. But in this method, what values are being assigned for x,y,z.. i dont know.

or any other code  to find Route half way on android.

Comment: The link you mentioned in your question, is only for getting exact midpoint of two lat,long. Not for map direction. So I suggest you to look in other way I also looking for it.

Comment: If possible look at any Location (Place) application for android it will uses same concept what you needed.

Comment: Also look at http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51822.html and http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing the line yourself, I'm assuming that you are drawing the line segments e.g. in the image above the first line segment going vertically (North?) on the image and the second line segment going horizontally (East?). If so, then it should be a simple matter of calculating the total distance of the line segments, finding the half-way distance and then subtracting line segment lengths in specific order until you can't - The bit that's left is the distance to the half-way point along the current line segment.