# Passing an ArrayList of Doubles to another class

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I was looking for some help I've spent the last few days trying to pass an `ArrayList of Doubles` into another class from an AsyncTask with no success and I am now thinking I should pass the array back to the mainActivity and then run it to the ProxAlert class from there. Is this the way to do it or am I over complicating it? Thanks for your help.

```
try{
        ArrayList<LatLonPair> nPosition = new ArrayList<LatLonPair>();
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


        System.out.println("Length"+ jArray.length());
        Log.d("DB","Length"+jArray.length());

        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){

                JSONObject json_data = null;

                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int eventID = i +1;
                String title = json_data.getString("Title");
                double latitude = json_data.getDouble("Lat"); 
                double longitude = json_data.getDouble("Lon"); 

                LatLonPair p = new LatLonPair(latitude , longitude);
                nPosition.add(p);


                //System.out.println(eventID+"&"+latitude+"&"+longitude);
                System.out.println("this" + p.printPoints());                        
        }    

    }       
    catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Log.e("log_tag","Failed data as:\n"+result);                
    }    

        return nPosition;           
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LatLonPair> result) {
    new ProxAlert().registerIntents(result);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //Intent i = new Intent();
    //i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("nPositon",(ArrayList<LatLonPair>) result);

    //startARActivity();
}
```

I went to transfer it to the main thread but I would have to make it Parcelable and I'm just unsure as the most direct approach. Sorry the error that I get is

```
09-18 12:27:16.605: E/AndroidRuntime(20122): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System      services not available to Activities before onCreate()
 09-18 12:27:16.605: E/AndroidRuntime(20122):   at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3562)
 09-18 12:27:16.605: E/AndroidRuntime(20122):   at com.example.test.ProxAlert.setProximityAlert(ProxAlert.java:51)
09-18 12:27:16.605: E/AndroidRuntime(20122):    at com.example.test.ProxAlert.registerIntents(ProxAlert.java:37)
09-18 12:27:16.605: E/AndroidRuntime(20122):    at com.example.test.retrieveDB.onPostExecute(retrieveDB.java:116)
09-18 12:27:16.605: E/AndroidRuntime(20122):    at com.example.test.retrieveDB.onPostExecute(retrieveDB.java:1)
09-18 12:27:16.605: E/AndroidRuntime(20122):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
09-18 12:27:16.605: E/AndroidRuntime(20122):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
09-18 12:27:16.605: E/AndroidRuntime(20122):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
```

Its instantiating before the onCreate(), thats why i was thinking it might be best to passed the array back to the main activity and then to the proxAlert.class

Comment: is there any error? what happens when you try to get `result` in `ProxAlert`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass ArrayList<Double> from one activity to another activity on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648312/pass-arraylistdouble-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-on-android)

Comment: @Simon: read the question again. This is not a duplicate

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using [LatLng](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html) class? It's available through the Google Play Services.

Answer (score 2):

The exception you get is the result of trying to get system services in the `ProxAlert` activity before the activity's onCreate() was called. Your `AsyncTask` doesn't respect the activity life cycle. You cannot instantiate an activity with `new`.

If you want to use other activites, then you must use Intents in the way it is described in this post: [Pass ArrayList<Double> from one activity to another activity on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648312/pass-arraylistdouble-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-on-android)

Comment: The array is made of LatLng pairs, I have 13 pairs that need to be passed into a proximity alert? I thought by putting them into an array they would be easier to pass. I'm fairly new to java and I think I've just over complicated it

Comment: You need to understand the lifecycle model and interactions that are possible. The question I linked in shows you how to pass data between activities using Intents.

Comment: OK I have created a `ArrayList<Parcelable>` and tried to pass it using intent but i can't run as `myActivity.this` wont work, I replaced it with activity and it runs but an error appears pointing back to `Intent i = new Intent(activity, ProxAlert.class);`

Comment: I think I worked out the problem the datasets didn't match, because the locations in the database were not written from a LocationManager they were missing some information required to used the proximityAlert so they couldn't be passed.. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I'm glad that you figured out. It's always good when an issue gets solved. :) I'm looking forward to helping more in the future. However, your code and the stack trace reflect the issues that I pointed out so in my opinion I answered your question. For future reference it would be better marking it the solution provided that you agree with my analysis.