# send Arraylist between two fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, fragment

bear with me, this is my first android app
and i need help to transfer arraylist (n) from fragment to another (frag1 to frag2).
i read about bundle and interface but i could not implement those solutions.
any detailed solution would be helpful.

here is my main acitvity

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("array_list");

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.colorAccent);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Split").setIcon(R.drawable.money));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Item List").setIcon(R.drawable.list));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Rates").setIcon(R.drawable.settings));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
```

here is my frag1

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View frag1v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag1, container, false);

    //Add Button//
    Button b = (Button) frag1v.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    final ArrayList<Double> n = new ArrayList<Double>();
    final EditText e = (EditText) frag1v.findViewById(R.id.sum);
    final EditText d = (EditText) frag1v.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final TextView tx = (TextView) frag1v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    final Double div = Double.parseDouble(d.getText().toString());

    // Shared Setting //
    SharedPreferences Setting_pre = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Setting", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String Discount_shared = Setting_pre.getString("Discount", "0");
    final String Service_shared = Setting_pre.getString("Service", "1.1");
    final String Tax_shared = Setting_pre.getString("Tax", "1.16");


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (e.getText().length() > 0) {
                Double e_double = Double.parseDouble(e.getText().toString());
                Double div = Double.parseDouble(d.getText().toString());
                Double sum_d = e_double / div;
                n.add(sum_d);
            }
            Double sum = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) {
                sum += n.get(i);
            }
            e.setText("");

            if (Discount_shared.equals("0")) {
                Double Discount_M = 1.0;
                Double sum_d = sum / div;
                Double Discount_Sum = sum_d * Discount_M;
                Double Service_M = Double.parseDouble(Service_shared.toString());
                Double Service_Sum = Discount_Sum * Service_M;
                Double Tax_M = Double.parseDouble(Tax_shared.toString());
                Double Tax_Sum = Service_Sum * Tax_M;
                String Total = Tax_Sum.toString().format("%.2f", Tax_Sum);
                tx.setText(Total);
            } else {
                Double Discount_M = Double.parseDouble(Discount_shared.toString());
                Double sum_d = sum / div;
                Double Discount_Sum = sum_d * Discount_M;
                Double Service_M = Double.parseDouble(Service_shared.toString());
                Double Service_Sum = Discount_Sum * Service_M;
                Double Tax_M = Double.parseDouble(Tax_shared.toString());
                Double Tax_Sum = Service_Sum * Tax_M;
                String Total = Tax_Sum.toString().format("%.2f", Tax_Sum);
                tx.setText(Total);
            }


        }
    });

    //clear//
    Button c = (Button) frag1v.findViewById(R.id.clear_btn);
    c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            n.clear();
            tx.setText("0");
        }
    });


    return frag1v;

}
```

here is my frag2

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View frag2v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag2, container, false);



    return frag2v;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason that you cannot use bundle?

Comment: i do not know how to use it!

Comment: This can be helpful: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable at the beginning.
One more tip: work on your variables naming. Your code now is really unreadable.

Comment: also another way  is event based solution . You can go for Eventbus.

Answer (score -1):

Since your problem is that you want to know how to send it using a intent, this post adressed that issue: [Pass ArrayList<Double> from one activity to another activity on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648312/pass-arraylistdouble-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-on-android)

A code example:

> FirstActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
ArrayList<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<Double>();
listDouble.add(1111.00000);
listDouble.add(13331.00000);
intent.putExtra("arraylist", listDouble);
startActivity(intent);
```

> OtherActivity: (Retrieve Double ArrayList)

```
ArrayList<Double> listDouble = (ArrayList<Double>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
System.out.println("...serialized data.." + listDouble);
```

For fragment comunication take a look at this post: [Basic Communication between two fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments) or at the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

> ```
> public class YourActivity implements FragmentA.TextClicked{
> @Override
> public void sendText(String text){
>     // Get Fragment B
>     FraB frag = (FragB)
>         getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b);
>     frag.updateText(text);
> }
> ```
>
> }

// Fragment A defines an Interface, and calls the method when needed
public class FragA extends Fragment{

```
TextClicked mCallback;

public interface TextClicked{
    public void sendText(String text);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (TextClicked) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implement TextClicked");
    }
}

public void someMethod(){
    mCallback.sendText("YOUR TEXT");
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mCallback = null; // => avoid leaking, thanks @Deepscorn
    super.onDetach();
}
```

}

// Fragment B has a public method to do something with the text
public class FragB extends Fragment{

```
public void updateText(String text){
    // Here you have it
}
```

}