# Passing ArrayList<Double> through Intents

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with passing an `ArrayList` to another activity in Android Studio.

I created a `ArrayList` that holds the data type `Double`. The program should read it and print it in the console.

This is the code from the first activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ergebnisse.class);
 intent.putExtra("WLTP_list", Wlist);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And this is the code from the second activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<Double> Wlist = (ArrayList<Double>) bundle.getDoubleArray("WLTP_list");
```

The part after the last equal sign is marked red and the error is:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'double[]' to 'Java.util.ArrayList<Java.lang.Double>'
```

I didn't change the type so I don't know why it is giving me that error.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What does `bundle.getDoubleArray` returns? Or, what `Wlist` is in the first snippet?

Comment: Is because `getDoubleArray` return `double[]` not `ArrayList<Double>`.See this doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass ArrayList<Double> from one activity to another activity on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648312/pass-arraylistdouble-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `bundle.getDoubleArray()`, which returns an array, instead of an ArrayList, that's why you're getting the error as you're trying to convert an double[] array into an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

The getDoubleArray() method returns an array of type double[], which cannot be explicitly cast to ArrayList. If you really want to use it as an ArrayList, you need to get that double[] array and explicitly convert it to an ArrayList. For instance, something like

```
 ArrayList<Double> Wlist = ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList( bundle.getDoubleArray("WLTP_list")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying this way.

**First Activity:**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    ArrayList<Double> listDouble = new ArrayList<Double>();
    listDouble.add(1.0);
    listDouble.add(2.0);
    intent.putExtra("WLTP_list", listDouble);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Second Activity:**

```
    ArrayList<Double> listDouble = (ArrayList<Double>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("WLTP_list");
System.out.println("Return.." + listDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your second activity instead:

```
ArrayList<Double> Wlist = (ArrayList<Double>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("WLTP_list");
```

The current method you are using returns an `Array` of the data type `Double`, not an `ArrayList`. The code I provided should give you an `ArrayList` instead.

If that line doesn't work, you can always look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648369/8212733) answer.